# Item margin affecting class margin

Tags: html, css, margin

This is my first ever HTML project and I'm trying to clone the Google Nigeria homepage. I'm about 90% completed, but I have issues that I've tried fixing, to no avail.

The 'app logo' and "Sign in" on the navigation is further up than the other items. I tried using margin-top on those nth items, but it affects the entire nav items.

Here: jsfiddle.net/mux9xbam/

Thanks.

Comment: You can post code here. You know that right?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Oh, yeah. The code is a tad long though, I dont know if that's allowed

Comment: You could atleast create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). It won't let you post a Fiddle without code though.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Thanks, I just created one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `float:left;` from `.first li a{}`

write

```
.first li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-size: .8em;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

instead of

```
.first li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-size: .8em;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    padding: 1px;
    float:left;
}
```

and adjust `margin padding` of `<ul>`

use

```
img
{
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

to align image middle.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mux9xbam/5/)

Comment: Thanks @Rasel, apparently, the "float: left" is useless there.
However, my intention is to move the 4th and 5th item further down. I'm using a margin top on them using the nth-child selector, but not working.

If there's another way to place all the items on same line, that'd be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Although, the image isn't showing correctly on jsfiddle, there's supposed to be an icon before the "sign in". The icon isn't centered correctly as the other items on the list.

Comment: I understand, Rasel. I will, as soon as it works :)
However, the icon still isn't centered

Comment: Now image is centered align

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me specifically what I did wrong and how you corrected it?

Comment: by default image inside its container li was not aligned to middle of li vertically.So set its alignment to middle place it proper place.You can get more by googling html elements alignments